# What mistake did I make in my code?

Tags: php

So I got this question from school:

A student won a price of $100,000 and puts it on her saving account from the 1st of January for 4% interest a year. At the end of every year she withdraws $5,000.

If she reaches 45 years display a different message, otherwise how long she can continue this.

What I came up with:

```
<?php

$start = 100000;
$year = 1;

do {
    $start = $start - 5000;
    $start = $start * 1.04;
    $year++;
} while ($start > 0);

if ($year > 45) {
    echo "Longer than 45 years";
} else {
    echo "Amount of years: $year";
}
```

The problem: My teacher said the answer should be 40, not 39. Does anyone know where my mistake lies?

Comment: `>=` rather than just `>` since you start at `1`?

Comment: @kkuilla really? -_-

Comment: Unrelated: I've cleaned your code up a little (tidy, readable code is more maintainable than clever code) and removed the closing `?>` tag - if the file **only** contains PHP, you don't need it

Comment: Its not a php problem and why would you write a title like that..

Comment: @UzumakiNaruto looks like he's writing in PHP, and are you going to suggest something better for a title or just take potshots at him?

Comment: just because he put a $ before every variable and used echo instead of print , cout , printf etc doesn't make this a php problem. I am just suggesting if you want help might as well write the title in such a way that it points to the problem area ... and yes looking at the code this could be done in any language... its the logic he's after that how to calculate..

Comment: @UzumakiNaruto So why are there tags like php and c++ on Stackoverlow? Based on what you said, there should be tags only for frameworks, not languages, right?

Comment: an algorithm tag or an equation tag n for the title ow common anything but "why my code doesn't work" .. I am not gonna argue he already got two down votes hence my point...

Answer (score 0):

year should start from 0, not 1. You are using a do[]while statement, not a while{}

moreover, she can continue withdrawing only if she has cash, so the guard inside while() should be

```
while($start > 5000)
```

Comment: Still doesn't get me 40, obviously

Comment: because it's not exactly 5000 but 5000 plus the interest computed for the next year :-)

Comment: you also need to clarify this: interests are computed and added at the end of the year, she withdraws money at the end of the year. which one come first? that's important as you should swap the two lines $start = $start - 5000;$start = $start * 1.04;. You get off-by-one error because the problem is not well defined.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$start = 100000;
$year = 0;
while ($start > 5000)
{
    $year++;
    $start = $start * 1.04;
    $start = $start - 5000;
}

if ($year > 45)
{
    echo "Longer than 45 years";
}
else
{
    echo "Amount of years: $year";
}
```